# construct date in a different locale than current

Tags: c++, c

I have a requirement, where a datetime, locale and daylight savings is input as fixed length string, such as `YYMMDDHHMMCY`, where the legend is provided below.

1. YY(year)
2. MM(month)
3. DD(day)
4. HH(hour)
5. MM(minute)
6. Timezone (C for central, P for Pacific, M for mountain, E for eastern)
7. Daylight savings (Y if daylight savings is in effect, other wise N)

What is needed is the ability to construct time in a specified timezone and then convert it to local timezone in C/C++. We dont use Boost, are there existing functions which would allow for the requirements. I am aware of `strptime`, which after some massaging the data, i can use it, but i am wondering if there are functions as described above which would allow me to construct a struct in a specified locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sscanf()` or `strptime()` to extract most of the fields.  The timezone character and DST character will need to be decoded on their own.  Since you are using only a 2 digit year, your need to define your range.  Example below uses 1970-2069.  Use the extracted timezone character to form the usual timezone name.  Before calling `mktime()`, set TZ to the timezone name.  Then, with a `time_t` in hand, convert to your local time.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

extern time_t mktime_TZ(struct tm *tm, const char *tz);
extern time_t DecodeTimeString_time_t(const char *time_string);

void DecodeTimeString_Local(const char *time_string, struct tm *local) {
  // Various error handling not shown
  time_t t;
  t = DecodeTimeString_time_t(time_string);
  *local = *localtime(&t);
}

time_t DecodeTimeString_time_t(const char *time_string /* YYMMDDHHMMCY */) {
    struct tm tm;
    char Zone, DST;
    int result = sscanf(time_string, "%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d%[CEMP]%[NY]",
        &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon, &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &Zone, &DST);
    if (result != 7) {
      ; // handle error
    }
    // Your need to decide how to handle 2 digits years
    // Assume 70-99 is 1970-1999 and 0 to 69 is 2000-2069
    if (tm.tm_year < 70) tm.tm_year += 2000-1900;
    tm.tm_mon--;  // Assume DateString used "01" for January, etc.
    tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_isdst = Zone == 'Y';
    const char *TZ;
    switch (Zone) {
      case 'P':  TZ = "PST8PDT"; break;  // Pacific
      case 'M':  TZ = "MST7MDT"; break;  // mountain
      case 'C':  TZ = "CST6CDT"; break;  // central
      case 'E':  TZ = "EST5EDT"; break;  // eastern
    }
    time_t t = mktime_TZ(&tm, TZ);
    return t;
    }

// Form time_t from struct tm given a TZ
time_t mktime_TZ(struct tm *tm, const char *tz) {
  time_t t;
  const char *old_tz = getenv("TZ");
  if (setenv("TZ", tz, 1 /* overwrite */)) {
    return -1; // handle error
  }
  tzset();
  t = mktime(tm);
  if (old_tz) {
    if (setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1 /* overwrite */)) {
      return -1; // handle error
    }
  }
  else {
    if (unsetenv("TZ")) {
      return -1; // handle error
    }
  }
  tzset();
  return t;
}
```

Comment: After re-setting the environment variable TZ, back to the old variable, you should call tzset(); again.

Comment: @Jimm the posted code all ready does call `tzset()`, right before `return t`.  It does not call `tzset()` on error handling as that area of code would need to be expanded per the OP (which I now notice is you).